# A triple integral over the unit ball

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

I'm trying to find the following triple integral over the unit ball.

$$\iiint_{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1} e^{(1-x^{2}-y^{2})^{3/2}} {\rm d} x \, {\rm d} y \, {\rm d} z$$

I am able to find a suitable parametrization but I can't get the bits in the exponent in terms of $r$.  Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Shoudn't there be a $z^2$ term in the integrand?

Comment: There isn't one.

Comment: I presume you mean the unit ball and not the unit sphere? As the unit sphere usually means a surface.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Use cylindrical coordinates, integrating with respect to $z$ on the inside.

Comment: I'm a little confused--if we're integrating over x^2+y^2+z^2 </= 1, how do we use cylindrical coordinates? I've not used them before so a little unfamiliar.

Comment: You need to translate the inequality $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1$ into conditions on $r, \theta, z$. The angle $\theta$ is not involved, because the sphere has rotational symmetry about the $z$-axis, Do you know how to express $r$ in terms of $x, y$?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1564074)

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you for your comments. The OP specifically invited hints.

Answer (score 0):

The integral boils down to

$$\begin{aligned} I &= \iiint ^{\sqrt{1-\left( x^{2} +y^{2}\right)}}_{-\sqrt{1-\left( x^{2} +y^{2}\right)}} e^{\left( 1-x^{2} -y^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} {\rm d} z \, {\rm d} x \, {\rm d} y\\ &= 2\iint e^{\left( 1-x^{2} -y^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\sqrt{1-\left( x^{2} +y^{2}\right)} {\rm d}x \, {\rm d}y \end{aligned}$$

where the double integral must be calculated over the unit circle. Substitute $x = r \cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$

$$\begin{aligned} I=\iint e^{\left( 1-r^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\sqrt{1-r^{2}} rdrd\theta \\
=\int ^{1}_{0} e^{\left( 1-r^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\sqrt{1-r^{2}} rdr\cdotp \int d\theta \\ \end{aligned}$$
Consider the integral

$$\begin{aligned}A=\int ^{1}_{0} e^{\left( 1-r^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\sqrt{1-r^{2}} rdr\ \end{aligned}$$
Substitute$$\begin{aligned}\ 1-r^{2} =t^{2}\\
-2rdr=2tdt\\
rdr=-tdt\\ \end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}{A=\int ^{1}_{0} e^{t}}^{3}\cdotp t^{2} dt=\frac{e-1}{3}\\
So,\ I=4\pi \cdotp \frac{e-1}{3}\\ \end{aligned}$$
Does this help?